# Optimising sql query with cartesian join

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables sl and sd.

I want to optimize the following query, if it is possible

```
select sl.*, sd.* from sl join sd where sl.conf_id='blah' and sd.for_as=1
```

My understanding is that the cartesian product is first performed and then filtering happens.

Is there a way to have the filtering done first?

Comment: There are relation between the two table ? .. if yes on which column?

Comment: @scaisEdge There is a relation between the 2 tables that is not included in the query above. THe actual query is a union of 2 selects, one query with inner join on the related column and the second half mentioned in the question above.

I need to optimize this half.

Comment: `My understanding is that the cartesian product is first performed and then filtering happens.` no, mysql usually can optimize it, anyway - check execution plan to confirm what is actually going on

Comment: This query should return an error complaining about the missing `ON`. And if you actually need a CROSS join MySQL should be smart enough to apply the WHERE-conditions before the join.

Answer (score 0):

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- it will probably say "Using join buffer".  This is where it loads one table into memory (if not too big) and repeatedly scans it for the data.  Not a pretty site, but a lot faster than before the 'join buffer' came into play.

Since you have no `ON` or `WHERE` tying the two tables together, you really want the "cross join"?  That is, if there are 40 'blah' and 70 '1', you will end up with 40*70 = 2800 rows?

As for optimizing, the optimizer will pick one of the tables, giving preference to one that has a useful index, scan it (index or table), then repeatedly use the join buffer (if possible) to scan (index or table) of the other.

In other words, one table will use an index if possible, doing the filtering before the Cartesian product, the other might use the join buffer.  If the tables aren't too big, the performance won't be too bad.